# Why do i need to add an asterisk?

Tags: c++, stl, stdstring

I have taken this exaple from cplusplus.com. I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string str ("Test string");
  for ( std::string::iterator it=str.begin(); it!=str.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

What purpose does the asterisk after "cout<<" have? If i remove that asterisk it gives me error C2679 in VC++, which commonly apears when you forget to include `<string>`, but in my case i have included `<string>`.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In it they will discuss iterators and how to work with them.

Comment: Because a `std::string::iterator` is different than a `char`, which is what the iterator is basically pointing to

Comment: actually this is old school and verbose method to iterate - more modern looks like this: `for (auto it : str) std::cout << it;`

Comment: @marcinj `it` is not a good name there; `c` or `ch` would be better

Comment: But it's not an iterator, @marcinj. It's different code from that shown in the question. It would be confusing to call a not-iterator `it`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I agree, `it` means iterator - and nothing else, here `c` is the best naming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asterisk in this case means "dereferencing". That is; don't print the iterator, print what the iterator points to (just like you'd dereference a pointer to print what it points to rather than just printing the value of the pointer).